# IdentityServer4 - Access AuthenticationToken information

Tags: identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

I'm using IdentityServer4 with Azure Active Directory.

I can authenticate and retrieve the username.

Now from my API I should access Graph and retrieve user information, mail, etc.

How can I read the **access_token** to request information from Graph?

This method save information in AutheticationProperty, Can I read this information? How?

```
    private void ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc(AuthenticateResult externalResult, List<Claim> localClaims, AuthenticationProperties localSignInProps)
    {
        // if the external system sent a session id claim, copy it over
        // so we can use it for single sign-out
        var sid = externalResult.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.SessionId);
        if (sid != null)
        {
            localClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.SessionId, sid.Value));
        }

        // if the external provider issued an id_token, we'll keep it for signout
        var id_token = externalResult.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token");
        if (id_token != null)
        {
            localSignInProps.StoreTokens(new[] { new AuthenticationToken { Name = "id_token", Value = id_token } });
        }
    }
```

I have tried adding information on "connect/userinfo" endpoint

```cs
GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true
```

UserInfo result:

```
{
  "sub": "subscription-id",
  "name": "Andrea Tosato",
  "preferred_username": "2942bf90-19d9-4518-bcb9-78026604bb3e"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, set `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` to true, due to loading user information in the User principal. *UserInfo* endpoint return user's information depends on your token scopes. If you need user's email you should request for *email* scope too. I think you can use *profile* and *email* scopes together for more information about the user.

Comment: Sorry, but I need access_token from Azure Active Directory.
I want to use this token with Graph. (User, Mail... and so on)